# Magento 2: insert products images alt tag programmatically

Tags: product, magento-2.1, image

I need to insert `ATL` tag for catalog products images programmatically. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Yes You can, but tell me which page and where you need to add it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the API interface `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementInterface`. You can add the image via the `create()` method, or update an existing entry via the `update()` method. Both methods require an instance of `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterface`, this interface has the `setLabel()` function that allows you to set the ALT tag for a product image.

I'm using a custom function to create images, it uses the above interfaces as factories. Updating an existing label/ALT tag works in the same way, but then using the `update()` function.

```
/**
 * Add image to product by SKU
 */
public function addImage(
    string $sku,
    string $filePath,
    array $imageTypes,
    string $destinationName,
    string $label = '',
    bool $disabled = false
): void {
    // Basic image data
    $data = file_get_contents($filePath);
    $base64 = base64_encode($data);
    $pathInfo = pathinfo($filePath);
    $fileExtension = strtolower($pathInfo['extension']);

    // Create media image
    $mediaImage = $this->mediaGalleryFactory->create();
    $mediaImage->setTypes($imageTypes);
    $mediaImage->setLabel($label);
    $mediaImage->setMediaType('image');
    $mediaImage->setDisabled($disabled);

    // Create content
    $content = $this->imageContentFactory->create();
    $content->setBase64EncodedData($base64);
    $content->setType("image/{$fileExtension}");
    $content->setName($destinationName);

    // Assign content to media and save image to product
    $mediaImage->setContent($content);
    $this->mediaGalleryManagement->create($sku, $mediaImage);
}
```

Constructor:

```
public function __construct(
    ImageContentInterfaceFactory $imageContentFactory,
    ProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementInterface $mediaGalleryManagement,
    ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterfaceFactory $mediaGalleryFactory,
) {
    $this->mediaGalleryFactory = $mediaGalleryFactory;
    $this->mediaGalleryManagement = $mediaGalleryManagement;
    $this->imageContentFactory = $imageContentFactory;
}
```

You can set the store view using the `setCurrentStore($storeCode)` function from `StoreManagerInterface`